# Plot continuous raster data in binned classes with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, raster

I quite like the look and feel of `ggplot2` and use them often to display raster data (e.g facetting over timesteps for time-varying precipitation fields is very useful).

However, I'm still wondering whether it is easily possible to **bin the continuous raster values into discrete bins and assign to each bin a single colour**, that is shown in the legend (as many GIS systems do).

I tried with the `guide = "legend"`, and `breaks` arguments of the `scale_fill_gradient` option. However these affect just the legend on the side of the graph, but the plotted values are still continuous.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x=rep(seq(1:10),times = 10), y=rep(seq(1:10),each = 10), value = runif(100,-10,10))
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "darkred", mid = "white", high = "midnightblue",
                       guide = "legend", breaks = c(-8,-4,0,4,8))
```

My question is mainly how to discretize the data that is plotted in `ggplot`, so that the reader of the graph can make quantitative conclusions on the values represented by the colors.

Secondly, how can I still use a diverging color palette (similar to `scale_fill_gradient2`), that is centered around zero or another specific value?

Comment: Another approach might be using `levelplot` from `rasterVis` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is indeed to modify the underlying data set by manually discretizing it. Below answer is based on the answer by [joran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982332/3915004).

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(x     = rep(seq(1:10),times = 10), 
                   y     = rep(seq(1:10),each = 10),
                   value = runif(100,-10,10))

# Define category breaks
breaks <- c(-Inf,-3:3,Inf)
data$valueDiscr <- cut(data$value,
                       breaks = breaks,
                       right = FALSE)

# Define colors using the function also used by "scale_fill_gradient2"
discr_colors_fct <- 
  scales::div_gradient_pal(low = "darkred",
                           mid = "white", 
                           high = "midnightblue")
discr_colors <- discr_colors_fct(seq(0, 1, length.out = length(breaks)))
discr_colors
# [1] "#8B0000" "#B1503B" "#D18978" "#EBC3B9" "#FFFFFF" "#C8C0DB" "#9184B7" "#5B4C93" "#191970"

ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = valueDiscr)) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = discr_colors) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=T))
```

[image]

## Update 2021-05-31:

Based on the comment by @slhck one can indeed discretize the data in the aesthetic mapping as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(x     = rep(seq(1:10),times = 10), 
                   y     = rep(seq(1:10),each = 10),
                   value = runif(100,-10,10))

# Define category breaks
breaks <- c(-Inf,-3:3,Inf)
discr_colors <- scales::div_gradient_pal(low = "darkred", mid = "white",  high = "midnightblue")(seq(0, 1, length.out = length(breaks)))
# [1] "#8B0000" "#B1503B" "#D18978" "#EBC3B9" "#FFFFFF" "#C8C0DB" "#9184B7" "#5B4C93" "#191970"

ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = cut(value, breaks, right=FALSE))) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = discr_colors) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=T))
```

[image]

Comment: This kind of discretization could also be easily performed by rounding (or using ceiling/floor functions) within the aesthetic mapping.

Answer (score 10):

You should use the `raster` package to work with raster data. This
package provides several function to work with categorical
rasters. For example, with `reclassify` you can convert a continuous
file into a discrete raster. The next example is adapted from
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940495/plot-raster-factor-values-with-ggplot):

```
library(raster)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
r <- reclassify(r, c(0, 500, 1,
                     500, 2000, 2))
```

On the other hand, if you want to use the `ggplot2` functions, the
`rasterVis` package provides a simple wrapper around `ggplot` that
works with `RasterLayer` objects:

```
library(rasterVis)

gplot(r) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill = factor(value))) +
    coord_equal()
```

[image: ggplot with raster]

to define your own colors you can add then:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','green')))
```

Comment: plus 1 since there is not more than 1 for `fill = factor(value)`